# Modulo vs overflow in int gives different result

Tags: c#

I was doing [advent of code](http://adventofcode.com/2017) day15 and as part of it I got an unexpected result. I had to basically calculate 16807 * 16807 * 65 and the value shouldn't be bigger than int.maxValue. I noticed that my result doesn't match with the expected result so when I simplified it, it basically boils down to this(unchecked wasn't used, it's just here to satisfy compiler):

```
 int a = unchecked(16807 * 16807 * 65); //1181022001
 long b = 16807L * 16807 * 65 % int.MaxValue; //1181022009
```

There may be something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: "16807 * 16807 * 65 and the value shouldn't be bigger than int.maxValue" But...it is.  It's 18,360,891,185.  int.maxvalue is 2,147,483,647.  The fact that you need to mark is as unchecked is precisely because the compiler is telling you it *is* larger than the max value.

Comment: I could be wrong, but doesn't `unchecked` just wrap around at the beginning of valid values (`int.MinValue`)? Of course that woudl have a different result than a modulo. The surprising thing is that the two values are that close.

Comment: Ok guys now I understood. It doesn't work because it doesn't overflow to 0 but it overflows to -int.MinValue. Sometimes I need to think a bit longer before posting.

Comment: @krillgar Why is it that surprising that they're close? When comparing `someLong % int.MaxValue` to incrementing an integer in an unchecked context infinitely the second one has *almost* twice as many values before looping around (2 less than half, in fact), so they're *almost* in phase half of the time, as you start cycling around.

Comment: @krillgar It probably makes the most sense why they're so often the same when you just look at a plot: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x+mod+2,147,483,647+and+(x+mod+4,294,967,295)+-+2,147,483,647

Comment: @Servy I guess I was thinking that if it looped around a couple of times, it would get pretty far off, but I see your point. It's also not something I had put too much thought into. Thank you for the link!

Comment: @krillgar Every time you go around the loop (~4 billion) you get off by 2.  The number here is ~18 billion; it's gone around 4 times, 4*2=8, so they're off by 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int.MaxValue + 1`, when cast to an integer (in an unchecked context) is `int.MinValue` (-2,147,483,648).  `(int.MaxValue + 1L) % int.MaxValue` is `1`.  So yes, they're both different, because they're both defined to do different things.